# Estimating the rank of a large sparse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a large sparse n by n matrix.  Are there any methods to estimate its rank in time roughly proportional the number of elements in the matrix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has also been studied from the property testing / query complexity point of view. For example:

> Li, Wang, & Woodruff. [Improved Testing of Low Rank Matrices](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2623330.2623736), KDD '14. (Freely available version from author [here](http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/files/us-dpwoodru/lwwKDD.pdf).)

One thing they show is that one can test (with high probability) if an $n \times n$ matrix has rank $\leq r$ or requires an $\varepsilon$ fraction of its entries to be changed in order to get rank $\leq r$ by querying only $O(r^2 / \varepsilon)$ entries of the matrix.

Answer (score 12):

There is a very neat randomized algorithm by [Cheung, Kwok, and Lau](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.6705), which computes the rank of an $n\times m$ matrix $A$, $n\le m$, in time $O(\mathrm{nnz}(A) + \min\{n^\omega, n\cdot\mathrm{nnz}(A)\})$. Here $\mathrm{nnz}(A)$ is the number of nonzero elements of $A$, and $\omega$ is the matrix multiplication exponent. Not quite what you are asking for, but it does improve on fast matrix multiplication based methods for $\mathrm{nnz}(A) = o(n^{\omega - 1})$.

Comment: Thank you. This is relevant but much slower than I was looking for.

Comment: I realize that. A trivial observation: you cannot hope for anything better than $O(\mathrm{nnz}(A)^\omega)$, because you can always embed an $n\times n$ matrix into a bigger matrix padded with zeros.

Comment: That observation is for the exact rank right? I would be happy with an approximation.

Comment: I see. This is not very clear from your question.